# drools cep current date

Tags: date, drools, complex-event-processing

I am using drools 6 + CEP (fusion) and I need to check that certain event happened 10 min before the current time the rule is checked. For this, I made the following approach:

```
rule "Before rule test"
when
    $fall : Fall()
    $current : Date(this after[10m] $fall)
then
    System.out.println("Fall older than 10m at least");
```

end

This is working correctly if I insert a fact `new Date()` every run, so I am wondering if I there is any object to do something like this:

```
rule "Before rule test"
when
    $fall : Fall(this before[10m] drools.currentDate)
then
    System.out.println("Fall older than 10m at least");
```

end

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same problem, here is our answer (not sure it is the best way).

We are working in Cloud mode with periodic fireAllRules call.

```
declare TickTocker
@propertyReactive
    Now : DateTime
end

rule "CreateTickTocker"
when
    not($tickTocker:TickTocker())
then
     TickTocker tickTocker = new TickTocker();
     tickTocker.setNow(new DateTime());
     insert(tickTocker);
end

rule "UpdateTickTocker"
timer (cron: 0/1 * * * * ? )
when
    $tickTocker:TickTocker()
then
    modify($tickTocker){
        setNow(new DateTime())
    }
end
```

usage:

```
rule "AlertOnLatency"
when
    $tickTocker:TickTocker()
    $monitored:MyObject(
        PeremptionDate < $tickTocker.Now)
then
    raiseAlert($monitored);
end
```

Comment: This approach is very helpful, but I can see there is a problem if you want to use PseudoClock, because the "date" you are setting to "TickTocker" will be the system one, not the one from PseudoClock

Comment: You are right. Is it possible to modify the setNow of TickTocker in UpdateTickTocker to use `session.getSessionClock().getCurrentTime()` instead of a simple `new DateTime()` ?

Comment: "session" is not recognized by DRL. That option is the one I was looking at the very begining, without necesary to put dependencies on drools jars inside model